# What is the difference between passing in a function VARIABLE to an event listener versus passing in a function REFERENCE?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Aka: What is the difference between:

Example 1:

```
button.onclick = foo;

var foo = function() {
           before = document.getElementById(“before”);
           var after = document.createElement(“div”);
           before.replaceWith(after);
}
```

Note that `foo` is NOT called with parens(), and it is defined with `var foo`.

Versus:

Example 2:

```
button.onclick = bar();

function bar () {
           before = document.getElementById(“before”);
           var after = document.createElement(“div”);
           before.replaceWith(after);
}
```

Note that `bar` is called with parens(), and it is defined with `function bar().`

It seems to me that the second option should allow you to pass in arguments to the function (say I pass in: `bar(“title”)` because I want to set `after.id = “title”`). However, whenever I call the function with parens () (so, `bar()`, whether in `onclick = bar()` or `addEventListener("click", bar())`, I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: before.replaceWith is not a function.`

---

Other details:
Someone else told me the problem is rooted in JavaScript asynchronous program execution. In particular, they gave me a metaphor of an airplane preparing to take flight versus the airplane actually launching.

The airplane might have been told the flight take off area, and told what it needs everything to do, but it hasn’t been signaled to launch yet.

With the function variable, all the preparation is ready before launch. Whereas with the function reference, the plane is not prepared beforehand, so “before” has not yet been identified and selected prior to `before.replaceWith` getting called, which is why I get the Uncaught TypeError.

Are there any good resources where I can read up on this? Are there any good metaphors you like to use?

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` property needs to contain a function. The function will be called when the click event occurs.

Your first code snippet does that. It sets the property to the `foo` function.

Your second snippet doesn't set the property to a function. Instead, it calls the function when you do the assignment, and sets the property to the result of the function. You're getting an error because the `before` element doesn't exist at the time of the assignment.

If you want to pass arguments to the function, you can do that using an anonymous function:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    someFun(arg1, arg2);
};
```